# Is there an equivalent in swift to Go's empty interface?

Tags: swift, go, interface

Is there an equivalent in Swift to pass as an argument an empty interface{} like in Go?

Comment: What do you try to achieve?

Comment: The answer is `Any`, but you almost certainly don't want this. `interface{}` solves problems that are solved in completely different ways in Swift.

Comment: I would like to pass any function(that could have any number of parameters, any type etc.) as a parameter of another function.

Comment: @NoemiPecorari That's probably not something you want to do in Swift. You'd have to cast the `Any` value down to a function type, and you would have a hard time knowing what to cast it as. What are you trying to achieve with that function?

Comment: @NoemiPecorari You'll need to redesign. Even in Go, I don't believe this would be the right design. What would you expect to do with "literally any function?" You couldn't call it or get results from it without first knowing its shape. If you knew its shape, you wouldn't need this feature. I suggest laying out the deeper problem you're trying to solve with this design. (Is it perhaps that you have one of a list of function signatures that you want to accept, rather than literally any function signature at all?) If you need to `as` cast or `reflect` to use it, you're probably on the wrong road.

Comment: (Go often uses `interface{}` and `reflect` to get around the fact that it has no generics. Swift has generics, and so usually don't need those tools.)

Comment: Yes there’s a list of function signatures that I want to accept but I wanted to know if there’s another way apart from overloading.

Answer (score 3):

I am not very familiar with Go, but I think the Swift equivalent would be an argument of type `Any` or `AnyObject`. You can't do much with such an argument other than try to cast it to a more specific type.

Answer (score 2):

Go's interfaces and Swift's protocols are quite different:

- Golang's interfaces are "structural" (akin to C++'s ["Concepts"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B))), meaning that their identity is defined by their structure. If a go struct has the structure required by an interface, it implicitly *implements* that interface. That is, the struct doesn't say anywhere "I am strust `S`, and I implement interface `I`."
- Swift's protocols are "nominal", meaning that their identity is defined their name. If a Swift struct fulfills all of the requirements of a protocol, it doesn't conform to that protocol, unless an explicit `struct S: P { ... }` declaration is made (the body of that declaration can even be empty, but it's still necessary for the conformance to exist).

The closest analogue to `interface{}` in Swift is `Any`. It's built-in protocol to which all type conform. It gets special treatment, it's defined by the compiler, and has hard-coded logic to make all other types conform to it. You won't see `protocol Any {}` or `struct S: Any {}` declared anywhere explicitly. `AnyObject` is similar, and also gets special treatment. But no other Swift protocols do. Their conformance need to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaking Swift's equivalent would be:

```
protocol EmptyProtocol {
}
```

In swift interfaces are called protocols don't ask me :D

Are you trying to do type erasure or something? Just curious...

Comment: Yes but I would like to pass as an argument an empty protocol like is possible in go..

Comment: I had to do a quick google search because I dont program in golang. I noticed that you can pass interfaces into functions too. So, the empty interface is used when the items inside are of any type? The only thing I can think of in swift are protocols with an associatedType but those can't be passed and only function as constraints on a type... I think what you are looking for doesn't exist in swift but maybe someone else will prove that theory wrong.